# What is the Best mixture ratio of Portland cement Quartz sand and bonding agent for under water application

Tags: tile, pool, thinset

I'm installing a ceramic mosaic in the bottom of my concrete pool and wondering what is the best mixture of white Portland cement Quartz sand and a bonding agent to apply this mosaic.  Can I just use white pool plaster to install?

Comment: Two things I do know about this, you will not want to use pool plaster to bond the tile, that is for the finish surface. The other is you will need to use an exterior grade thinset, but I do not know if it needs to be anything specific for pool use.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't want to be looking at a hydraulic cement or mortar rather than just Portland cement?

http://www.lowes.com/pd_41334-96-00924_0__?productId=3033247

Or something like this?  http://www.superior-industries.com/pro_patch_600_product_271.html

I'm not trying to advocate specific products or brands, but illustrating examples of products that are actually designed for underwater use.

If you were looking at one-off repair of loose or detached tiles, you might consider an underwater adhesive:  http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Adhesives/Tapes/Products/~/3M-Marine-Adhesive-Sealant-5200?N=5510818+3294314622&rt=rud